# Why is there no difference between variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I am a beginner in Python and just starting to learn from home. I did an exercise on creating a list containing friends and print them one by one. Then, I need to print them one by one including a message. The text of each message should be the same, but each message should be personalized with the person’s name. So, this is the first code:

```
names = ['John','Ben','Daniel','Nathan']
greetingJohn = f"Good morning {names[0]}."
print(greetingJohn)
greetingBen = f"Good morning {names[1]}."
print(greetingBen)
greetingDaniel = f"Good morning {names[2]}."
print(greetingDaniel)
greetingNathan = f"Good morning {names[3]}."
print(greetingNathan)
```

This is the second code:

```
names = ['John','Ben','Daniel','Nathan']
greeting = f"Good morning {names[0]}."
print(greeting)
greeting = f"Good morning {names[1]}."
print(greeting)
greeting = f"Good morning {names[2]}."
print(greeting)
greeting = f"Good morning {names[3]}."
print(greeting)
```

The output is the same for both:

```
Good morning John.
Good morning Ben.
Good morning Daniel.
Good morning Nathan.
```

So, I am confused why is there no difference between the 'greeting{name}' and only 'greeting'? Hopefully, you can answer my curious beginner question.

Comment: In the first case you are creating 4 variables from those 4 strings. in the second case you are assigning each string to the same variable. When you print after each assignment, the end result is the same. But in the first case you have 4 variables with 4 different values, while in the second case, you have one variable holding the value of the last string you assigned it to.

Comment: What rdas said - and just as a tip, for a case that simple you would usually not use a variable at all but rather just do `print(f'Good morning, {name}')`

Comment: It's not looking at the name of the variable to detemine what to print.  It's looking at the value of the variable.  You can name your variables anything you want.  The person's name is part of the string that's assigned to the variable.

Comment: What difference were you expecting, exactly?

Comment: One thing you would find very helpful in learning Python is to use a debugger and step through your code line by line. The debugger will show you the values of all your variables after you step over each line. By doing that, you would gain an immediate understanding of questions like this. The [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) is free and has an excellent debugger. There are other good debuggers too, but you won't go wrong with PyCharm. Try installing it and then step through your code. This will really help you out.

Comment: Thanks @ThiefMaster. I think that's simpler.

Comment: Understood. Thanks all for the clarifications.

Comment: @Paul M. I was expecting like the variable greeting would print the first assigned variable. But, turns out the opposite. I got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python whenever assign a value to a variable, you are actually binding the variable with the reference to the memory location where the created object is stored. Whenever this variable is reassigned a new value, the binding with the previous object is removed (though the object still stays in the memory) and the variable is bound to the newly created object. Hence greeting{name} and greeting acts the same. The name of the variable doesn't matter here, it's  the value it points to.

Answer (score -1):

In python, you have the choice to declare any variables you want. A variable is a bit of information that you want to assign to anything represented. `GreetingName` has the same bits of information as a normal greeting.